# SAS: Using proc freq for a two-by-two table; how do I include all levels of Y?

Tags: sas, output, frequency, missing-data

I feel like this should be really easy and obvious, but I can't figure it out. Any advice is appreciated!

It starts with just a simple crosstab. I need the output to be a list of values of x (number of events) for each level of y (regions), of which there are 13. There are 4 types of events, and I need a table to summarize each. Occasionally, there are 0 events in a region. However, I need the output to list all 13 regions. Is there some ridiculously simple solution that I've just overlooked? I tried the sparse option, and it didn't work.

```
proc freq data = have noprint;
    table region * num_events / nopercent norow nocol
    out = want;
run;
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Sadly, no simple option for PROC FREQ.  I would typically switch to PROC TABULATE, which supports PRELOADFMT option (PROC MEANS does as well).  Found a paper on tricking PROC FREQ: https://pharmasug.org/proceedings/2015/QT/PharmaSUG-2015-QT33.pdf  And another paper about PRELOADFMT: https://www.pharmasug.org/proceedings/2012/CC/PharmaSUG-2012-CC26.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin! Much appreciated! And I feel a little less idiotic!